# AS2: For loop found number but string is required

Tags: flash, actionscript, actionscript-2

Here is the snippet of my code which is causing this error:

```
    for (a=0; a<cabinets[index].length; a++) {
        if (cabinets[index][a].xPos>cabinetMap.xPos) {
            var newX:Number = cabinets[index][a].xPos-symbolParams.X_SPACING;
            enableSwitch(cabinets[index][a].mc,false);
            TweenMax.to(cabinets[index][a].mc,0.4,{_x:newX, ease:Expo.easeOut, onComplete:enableSwitch, onCompleteParams:[this, true]});
        }
    }
```

Which produces the following error:

**Description:** `Type mismatch in assignment statement: found Number where String is required.`

**Source:** `for (a=0; a<cabinets[index].length; a++) {`

Which is peculiar because when I alter it to: `for (a="0"; a<cabinets[index].length; a++) {` it throws no errors anymore however this is now incorrect because `a` is now a string.

Any ideas as to why this could be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am assuming you have declared a variable called `a` someone before that block of code and that it has either been explicitly or implicitly set to a `String` type.

Comment: This was the case, it was `for (var a in drinks) {` causing the problem at the start of my code but should that be setting it to a string type?

Comment: when you use a `for..in` loop like that, it will only accept `String` or `Òbject` type for the assignment var (in this case `a`). As you didn't explicitly set a type, it took it as `String` - you should have a "no type definition set" warning